# Fontello in IE8

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-8, fontello

I'm using [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) to display icons which works on every browser except for IE8 (it works fine in IE7). I've included every file that comes with Fontello and the URLs to each file is correct. In IE8 the fonts are instead displayed as a box rather than the desired font.

I've done some searching on this and haven't yet found my answer. I did find that IE8 might not understand the codes for Fontello which could be changed (https://github.com/fontello/fontello/issues/70) but I didn't really understand this and was hoping someone may be able to help or guide me on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/fontello/fontello/issues/71#issuecomment-7580473

Copied from comment there:

I had a similar issue also - a combined symbol font from fontello was not displaying on IE8 or Opera. In case anyone else stumbles upon this thread, here's what I did:

1) I had to go to fontsquirrel as mentioned in the first post, and use the TTF font generated from fontello to create the woff, svg and eot.
2) I had to include: font-weight:normal; in my @font-face declaration. This single thing caused Opera to work perfectly, after hours of frustration with messed up glyphs.

I'm not sure how related these two things are, but togther they brought everything into line for me. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

IE wants the fontello styles inline in your base/main template. You can call it within style tags in a conditional comment so it only loads this way in ie.